# Increment column value in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, auto-increment

Data type of test_id is int(4) 
I am trying to increment the value of test_id by 1.

Below is the table

```
test_id   name   location

 245      Frank    CA
 245      Roy      MO
 245      Tom      KS
 245      Chris    KS
 245      Harry    MO
```

Output expected

```
  test_id   name   location

   245      Frank    CA
   246      Roy      MO
   247      Tom      KS
   248      Chris    KS
   249      Harry    MO
```

Comment: Please show us how exactly you are "*trying*".

Comment: It's impossible, because the ordering is random

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the other values uniquely define each row, you can use `row_number()` and a `join`:

```
update t
    set test_id = test_id + seqnum
    from (select t.*, row_number() over () - 1 as seqnum
          from t
         ) tt
    where tt.name = t.name and tt.location = t.location;
```

You might want an `order by` for `row_number()` to get the results with a particular ordering.